# DisplayLink Display nearly working on 10.10

Tags: 10.10, multiple-monitors, screen, displaylink, logo

Here's what they look like at the moment. Here are 2 images: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yHMIZ.jpg and https://i.stack.imgur.com/yHMIZ.jpg.

I can't seem to find anyone else with this screen, and I've just installed libdlo drivers. I've seen other posts where people have gotten it to work after editting their xorg.conf, but I can't seem to find that either.

Answer (score 0):

I played around with using DisplayLink under Linux and encountered problems related to the fact that Linux is still not very good at supporting multiple display adapters (unlike Windows) which, in my case, meant that my NVIDIA drivers won't work at the same time as the DisplayLink or fbdev drivers.

If you just want to try out the DisplayLInk (or multiple DisplayLinks) take a look at [this](http://plugable.com/2011/12/23/usb-graphics-and-linux/), for example.

Good Luck.